# Make Any Observable act like ReplaySubject

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I've been attempting to get my stream to replay only the latest value with little luck. Basically, I've got a `replaySubject(1)` in a place where I can't just manually `.onNext` it. What I would like to do is take it, map it to something else, then add an initial value.

My first instinct was the following:

```
var testInStream = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
var testOutStream = testInStream.startWith(-1);

testInStream.onNext(0);

setTimeout(function(){
       testOutStream.subscribe(function(x){ 
       console.log("stream:", x);
   });
}, 1000);
```

Which prints

```
stream: test -1
stream: test 0
```

However, I would like to find a way to only print `stream: test 0`. The closest thing I can come up with is

```
var testInStream = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
var testOutStream = testInStream.startWith(-1);

testInStream.onNext(0);

var wrapperSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
testOutStream.subscribe(function(new_val){ wrapperSubject.onNext(new_val) });

setTimeout(function(){
  wrapperSubject.subscribe(function(x){ 
    console.log("stream:", x);
  });
}, 1000);
```

Which returns

```
stream: test 0
```

Which is what I want. But, I would rather not create an intermediate replaySubject, I would prefer to just call something like `testOutStream.latest()` or `testOutStream.replay(1)` but I've yet to get any of them to work.

Any help is appreciated, here's a [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/hiketa/edit?js,console) with my examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shareReplay(1)`, example code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pujvgn3z/1/)

```
var validation$ = Rx.Observable
 .fromEvent(document.getElementById('validation'), 'click')
 .map(function(_, index){
   return ++counter;
   })
 .do(emits(ta_validation, 'index'))
 .shareReplay(1)

validation$.subscribe(function(){})

setTimeout(function() {
  validation$
  .do(emits(ta_result, 'second subscription'))
  .subscribe(function(){    });}, 3000)
```

I naively tried with `replay(1)` and `connect` but strangely the whole stream values get replayed. So best is to use `shareReplay`.

Also take in mind that the following operators can be of use depending on what exactly you want to do with that 'latest' value:

- [combineLatest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md)
- [withLatestFrom](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md)

Comment: it looks like shareReplay was removed in RxJs 5 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: yes but the OP is using `.onNext` to use its subjects, so that means that he is using Rxjs v4 or lower. Actually from the jsbin, OP uses 4.0.6

Answer (score 0):

There is a cleaner solution. The little known secret is the observers (for example Subject) can be passed as a subscription handler. So the code that does the work is:

```
var testInStream = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
// var testOutStream = testInStream.startWith(-1);

var testOutStream = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
testInStream.startWith(-1).subscribe(testOutStream);

testInStream.onNext(0);

setTimeout(function(){
       testOutStream.subscribe(function(x){ 
       console.log("stream:", x);
   });
}, 1000);
```

see [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/rodude/1/edit?js,console).